# Dynamic param page evaluation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Using **Puppeteer** to scrape different element types from HTML page

```
const evaluation = await page.evaluate(
    () => [...document.querySelectorAll('h2')].map(elem => {
        return elem.className
    })
  )
```

I would like **'h2'** to be a dynamic parameter

```
const elementName = "h2"
  const evaluation = await page.evaluate(
    () => [...document.querySelectorAll(elementName)].map(elem => {
        return elem.className
    })
  )
```

but when I try I get an error:

**Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: elementName is not defined**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following and it should work

```
const elementName = "h2"
  const evaluation = await page.evaluate(
    (elementName) => [...document.querySelectorAll(elementName)].map(elem => {
        return elem.className
    }), elementName
  )
```

Here is a resource you can look at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind